# How to update another column if one column is changed?

Tags: mysql

Here, I have table named `customer_ac` with fields `ac_no`, `amount`, `due_date`, `interest`, `total`.

If the `amount` goes above Rs. 30. Then `due_date` is created 7 days from today,

If the `due_date` is passed then `total` should be updated automatically.

How can I do this?

Comment: i have tried to improve your question to my best effort, just check if it aligns with your needs

Comment: Use triggers http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-the-first-trigger-in-mysql.aspx